# Requesting RSS feeds from two web sites in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, rss, request

I have got a Node.JS server that requests data from two web servers: [bbc.co.uk](http://bbc.co.uk) and [sky.com](http://sky.com). Then the RSS feeds are parsed, and a user sees two lists: from BBC and from sky.

Here is the code.

```
var feed = require('feed-read');
var http = require('http');
var async = require('async');
var request = require('request');

var LIMIT = 10;
var UNABLE_TO_CONNECT = "Unable to connect.";
var BBC_URL = 'http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml';
var SKY_URL = 'http://news.sky.com/feeds/rss/home.xml';

var server = http.createServer(onRequest);
server.listen(9000);

function onRequest(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type' : 'text/html; charset=utf-8'
    });

    async.parallel([ function(callback) {
        feed(BBC_URL, onRssFetched);
        // TODO: where to call callback()?
    }, function(callback) {
        feed(SKY_URL, onRssFetched);
        // TODO: where to call callback()?
    } ], function done(err, results) {
        console.log("Done");
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
    });
}

function onRssFetched(err, articles) {
    console.log("RSS fetched");
    var html = [];
    if (err) {
        html.push("<p>", UNABLE_TO_CONNECT = "</p>");
    } else {
        html.push("<ol>");
        var i = 0;
        articles.forEach(function(entry) {
            if (i == LIMIT) {
                return;
            }
            html.push("<li><a href='" + entry.link + "'>" + entry.title
                    + "</a></li>");
            i++;
        });
    }
    console.log(html.join(""));
}
```

Now I don't know how to add the result to the web page. If I call `callback()` right after calling the `feed` method, `callback()` will be executed without waiting until `feed` has completed its job. On the other hand, I can't pass `callback` to `feed`. Maybe the approach is wrong, and I need some other module for RSS parsing.

Comment: I'm confused, why isn't feed processing for BBC and SKY a separate request on server side?  Can't you just make two different requests on client side and that should solve your problem right?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

@Maksim I know your original question included the **async** module, but propose an alternative:

***why not*** **stream** *each article* to the client as it comes in rather than waiting for *all* RSS feeds to return before sending a response...?

By using **async.parallel** you are telling node:

> "*wait until we have a response from* ***all*** *these news services 
>
>   and only* ***then*** *(combine the articles into) a* ***single*** *response to the client* ..."

This uses up memory for each connected client while you wait for all responses (from the RSS news services) ... *wasteful*.

So I've written my answer without resorting to **async**. 
And, instead of waiting for *ages* (while **async** combines all the feeds into one), 
 
the client sees news as soon as the ***first*** rss feed returns!

```
var feed = require('feed-read'),  // require the feed-read module
    http = require("http"),
    urls = [
        "http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml",
        "http://news.sky.com/feeds/rss/home.xml",
        "http://www.techmeme.com/feed.xml"
    ]; // Example RSS Feeds

http.createServer(function (req, res) { 
    // send basic http headers to client
    res.writeHead(200, {
        "Content-Type": "text/html",
        "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked"
    });

    // setup simple html page:
    res.write("<html>\n<head>\n<title>RSS Feeds</title>\n</head>\n<body>");

    // loop through our list of RSS feed urls
    for (var j = 0; j < urls.length; j++) {

        // fetch rss feed for the url:
        feed(urls[j], function(err, articles) {

            // loop through the list of articles returned
            for (var i = 0; i < articles.length; i++) {

                // stream article title (and what ever else you want) to client
                res.write("<h3>"+articles[i].title +"</h3>"); 

                // check we have reached the end of our list of articles & urls
                if( i === articles.length-1 && j === urls.length-1) {
                    res.end("</body>\n</html>"); // end http response
                } // else still have rss urls to check
            } //  end inner for loop
        }); // end call to feed (feed-read) method
    } // end urls for loop
}).listen(9000);
```

**Key Advantages**:

- The people connecting to your app will see news/results **Much faster** (almost instantly!)
- Your app uses *much* **less memory**
- You don't have to edit/update any *code* when you add new RSS news feeds!

> For even more detail/notes on this solution 
>  
>   see: https://github.com/nelsonic/node-parse-rss

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need another library. But what you need to do is to hand over `callback` to your `feed` function instead of `onRssFetched`. This way the single RSS feeds are handed over to the final callback in your `async.parallel` call, using the `result` variable.

In this variable you then have access to both RSS feeds at the same time, and you can do whatever you want to do with them.

So, basically your logic needs to be:

```
async.parallel({
  bbc: function (callback) {
    feed(BBC_URL, callback);
  },
  sky: function (callback) {
    feed(SKY_URL, callback);
  }
}, function (err, result) {
  if (err) {
    // Somewhere, something went wrong…
  }

  var rssBbc = result.bbc,
      rssSky = result.sky;

  // Merge the two feeds or deliver them to the client or do
  // whatever you want to do with them.
});
```

And that's it :-).

Answer (score 0):

To amplify @nelsonic's answer (enough that I feel this warrants its own answer), `feed-parse` already processes asynchronously.  At its heart, it's still running on http.request.  If you look at the code, you see that you can even pass in an array of URLs directly and it will loop through them, but it uses more of an "async.eachSeries" approach, where the next call only occurs after the previous one completes, which appears not to be what you're looking for.

If you truly want to wait for calls to complete first before handling them, you're better off asynchronously buffering the data, then using underscore's `_.after()` to run after all URLs have finished.

But odds are, what you really want to do (unless you're just looking for an example to try out async) is @nelsonic's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would ideally stream the rss data, instead of aggregating in memory. @nelsonic has explained the correct approach to solve this problem.

Still, if we were to make your code running, consider following code:

```
var util = require('util');
var http = require('http');
var async = require('async');
var feed = require('feed-read');
var request = require('request');

var LIMIT = 10;
var UNABLE_TO_CONNECT = 'Unable to connect.';
var BBC_URL = 'http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml';
var SKY_URL = 'http://news.sky.com/feeds/rss/home.xml';

var server = http.createServer(onRequest);
server.listen(9000);

function onRequest(req, res) {
  util.log('Request recieved!');
  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'
  });

  async.parallel({
    bbc: function (callback) {
      feed(BBC_URL, function (err, articles) {
        var html = onRssFetched(err, articles);
        callback(err, html);
      });
    },
    sky: function (callback) {
      feed(SKY_URL, function (err, articles) {
        var html = onRssFetched(err, articles);
        callback(err, html);
      });
    }
  }, done);

  function done(err, results) {
    util.log('Received results: ' + Object.keys(results).join(','));
    if (!err && results) {
      var entry, html;
      for (entry in results) {
        html = results[entry];
        res.write(html.join(''));
      }
      util.log('Send complete!');
      res.end();
    } else {
      console.log(err || 'no data in results');
      res.end('Unable to process your request');
    }
  }
}

function onRssFetched(err, articles) {
  // limit number of articles;
  articles = articles.slice(0, LIMIT);

  var html = [];
  if (err) {
    html.push('<p>', UNABLE_TO_CONNECT = '</p>');
  } else {
    html.push('<ol>');
    articles.forEach(function (entry) {
      html.push('<li><a href="' + entry.link + '">' + entry.title + '</a></li>');
    });

    html.push('</ol>');
  }
  return html;
}

// -- Test Code ---------------------------------------------------------
if (require.main === module) {
  (function () {
    var req, res = {
        writeHead: console.log,
        write: console.log,
        end: console.log
      };
    // onRequest(req, res);
  })();
}
```

Let me know if you face any issues.